# Spoof country where webserver is located

Tags: php, geolocation, seo, ip

I have several domainnames hosted on 1 VPS for example domainname.fr and domainname.es

The webserver is located in a France datacenter.

Now i have read that for SEO purposes it is best for domainname.fr to be hosted on a webserver located in France and for domainname.es te be hosted on a webserver that is located in Spain.

Is this something that can be spoofed? So let the searchengine **THINK** that the webserver is located in Spain (for the .es domainname) while it is actualy hosted on a webserver in France?

Comment: _"Now i have read that for SEO purposes it is best for domainname.fr to be hosted on a webserver located in...."_ What? I can see the performance reasons, but honestly not the SEO reasons, neither have I ever heard of it. - And for the sake of clarity, you mean that the web servers that the domains point to are hosted in X country, right?

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution would be to use a CDN like CloudFlare. They have datacenters in both [Spain and France](https://www.cloudflare.com/features-cdn/) so for a visitor it would seem that the traffic comes from a national server.

Note that I am not familiar with CloudFlare's algorithms so I don't know for sure that in Spain the Spanish data center would be used 100% of the time.

I am also not sure about the real effect it will have on SEO but as you will get ssl for free (in the case of CloudFlare...), there is definitely a positive effect if you don't use ssl yet.

An additional advantage is that you are not actually spoofing anything, you are really using data centers close to the visitor so a crack-down on spoofing / dubious SEO methods will not affect you in the future.

Answer (score -1):

> Now i have read that for SEO purposes it is best for domainname.fr to
>   be hosted on a webserver

This is totally incorrect. A country level domain like an .fr domain is already geo targeted to france and server location is irrelevant.